# How should jsp custom tag receive data?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I implemented my own jsp custom tag.
In it's body I find some data in database:

```
    public class CustomTag extends TagSupport {
         private LinkedList<User> sList = new LinkedList<Student>();

         @Override
         public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
           sList = new LinkedList<Student>(new myDao().findAll());
           JspWriter writer = pageContext.getOut();
          // try {....}
           //catch (Exception e) {
           return SKIP_BODY;
    }
}
```

But, I was told, that it is a bad practice.
How can I give some data in my custom tag?

Comment: please elaborate your question . one liner may suit for answer some times , but i dont believe it for questions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could pass a parameter to your tag

```
<ns:mytag sampleParameter="Hello">
```

In your tag :

```
   public class CustomTag extends TagSupport {
         private LinkedList<User> sList = new LinkedList<Student>();
         private String sampleParameter;


         @Override
         public int doStartTag() throws JspException {

           LOGGER.info("Parameter : "+sampleParameter);


           sList = new LinkedList<Student>(new myDao().findAll());
           JspWriter writer = pageContext.getOut();
          // try {....}
           //catch (Exception e) {
           return SKIP_BODY;
    }

     public void setSampleParameter(String sampleParameter)
     {
       this.sampleParameter = sampleParameter;
     }

     public String getSampleParameter()
     {
       return sampleParameter;
     }
}
```

In this case is just a string but it could be anything.